# Spring Cloud Config Client - Angel.SR4 vs Boot 1.3.1?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

All,

I've built Spring Cloud Config servers and clients before with previous versions of Spring Cloud / Spring Boot, but I seem to be having an issue with the Angel.SR4 / Boot 1.3.1 combination.

Following the basic instructions here (http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_client_side_usage), except using the current releases of Boot and Cloud (1.3.1.RELEASE / Angel.SR4 at present), I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:405)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

If I back off the Boot version to 1.2.8 the problem disappears.  If I move Cloud up to Brixton.M4 the problem disappears.  Is there a prescribed version combination of Boot / Cloud that should be used together?  Thanks in advance.

K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a prescribed version combination of Boot / Cloud that should be used together?

Yes. Angel is Boot 1.2, and Brixton is Boot 1.3. See the blog for more detail: https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/25/migrating-spring-cloud-apps-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-3